# Lightroom imports this years fotos into latest last years folder

Tags: lightroom, sony-alpha

My lightroom istallation puts all photos of 2023 into the last folder of 2022. I used to move them manually, but it bothers me.
Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

In case my camera model matters: Sony Alpha 7 IV

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When importing ensure the folder above the 2023 and 2022 folder is selected as the top folder. Lightroom will then import the dated folders into the correct year.

I suspect in you example you selected the folder 2022-12-10 before importing. Lightroom went ahead and created the desired folder structure of `YYYY/YYYY-MM-DD` under that folder.

Comment: Sadly even when selecting the top level folder it still does copy it into the 2023 folder under 2022

Comment: @peter can you post screenshots of the whole sidepanel showing the folder selection at import?